# Prevent to empty cart after failed/canceled payments in magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I am using PayuBiz as a online payment method in our website, in which cart is getting empty on failure /canceling of order and my code is:

```
 public function execute()
    {
        $arrParams = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $objectManager->create('\My\Payment\Model\Standard')->getResponseOperation($arrParams);
        $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->clear();
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/onepage/failure');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solutions for **Magento 2.3.5**. Please override **Failure.php**(Core file path: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage) and change ***public function*** as below

```
public function execute()
{
    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    
    $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
        $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        //$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage('Payment Failed.');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```